# How do I write a C++ requires expression that looks for specific member functions/static functions with arguments?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts, requires-expression

How can I write a [C++ requires expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/requires) that looks for specific member functions or static functions, with specific argument types?

For example:

```cpp
struct ConcretePrintable {
    static std::string StaticDescription() { return "static description"; }
    std::string Description() { return "description"; }
    std::string Greet(std::string_view name) { return std::format("Hi, {}!", name); }
};

template <typename T>
concept Printable = requires(T t) {
    { T::StaticDescription() } -> std::same_as<std::string>; // Require that T has a static function (that returns a string) named `StaticDescription`

    { t.Description() } -> std::same_as<std::string>; // Require that T have a member function (that returns a string) named `Description`

    // TODO: how to test for the `Greet` method?
    // { t.Greet(declval(std::string_view)) } -> std::same_as<std::string>;
};
```

https://godbolt.org/z/x5rG6fG87

Comment: Did you try `requires(T t, const std::string_view &s)`, and then checking for `t.Greet(s)`?

Comment: I did not try that; [that works](https://godbolt.org/z/51Mf744cE), but is that **really** the best syntax? Every function arg needs to appear in the requires expression? Am I "holding it wrong" with this design?

Comment: @citelao: What's wrong with that syntax? More importantly, you shouldn't treat concepts like they're base classes. They shouldn't just be a grab-bag of functions. You need to think about exactly what it is that these concepts represent.

Comment: Well, can you come up with an alternative syntax that's more compact, and concise, than that?

Comment: `{ t.Greet(std::string_view{}) } -> std::same_as<std::string>;` seems to work but I'm not sure if it is actually allowed.

Comment: @NathanOliver It's allowed - any expression goes. In this case it's fine since `string_view` is default-constructible, but it might not be an option for other types.

Comment: I've formalized some of these answers as a Community Wiki answer; thank you! Regarding `grab-bag of functions` - I agree; however, concepts are really great for simplifying error messages of templated classes---"I expect this set of methods." Yeah, it's not a *base class*, but I expect usage like this to be fairly common.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several approaches that work!

### Approach 1: if the types are default-constructable

```cpp
template <typename T>
concept Printable = requires(T t) {
    // ...

    // If the type is default-constructable:
    { t.Greet(std::string_view{}) } -> std::same_as<std::string>;
};
```

https://godbolt.org/z/s3KKvdMEz

### Approach 2: add the type to the requires statement

```cpp
template <typename T>
concept Printable = requires(T t, const std::string_view& s) {
    // ...

    { t.Greet(s) } -> std::same_as<std::string>;
};
```

https://godbolt.org/z/51Mf744cE